# JS function...Write a function to find the weekday of the user's birthday

Tags: javascript, function

-Use window.prompt to generate a dialog box asking the user to type in his/her birthday.

-Write a function to find the weekday of the user's birthday.

-Respond to the user with a sentence telling the user the weekday (weekday name) of his/her birthday. Ex. "You were born on a Wednesday."

-The script should include necessary data validation. Respond to the user appropriately when the date provided by the user is not a valid date. (However, future dates are allowed.)

I have no Idea how to do this.. (hw assignment) I have this currently.... and all this is doing for me is telling me I was born on Feb. 12 which is a thursday. I'm not too sure where to start. What kind of function do I need to make for this to work???

```
var bday;
bday = window.prompt("When is your birthday?","");

var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

var currentTime = new Date();

var currentDay = currentTime.getDay();

var currentDayName= days[currentDay];

document.write("You were born on "+currentDayName);
```

Comment: You don't appear to be *using* `bday` at all. Not a good sign.

Comment: I would have a look at how `Date` works... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date What happens if you don't pass any parameter to it?

Comment: thanks guys, I need to go over all of this....myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var bday;
bday = window.prompt("When is your birthday (YYYY-MM-DD)?","");
var bdayArray = bday.split('-');


//validation
if(bdayArray.length !== 3){
     alert("invalid Date");
}else{
    if(!bdayArray[0].match(/^\d\d\d\d$/) || 
       !bdayArray[1].match(/^\d\d$/) || 
       !bdayArray[2].match(/^\d\d$/)){
        alert("invalid Date");    
    }else{
        var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];     
        var currentTime = new Date(            
            parseInt(bdayArray[0]),
            parseInt(bdayArray[1]) - 1, //month starts from 0
            parseInt(bdayArray[2])
        );        
        var currentDay = currentTime.getDay();       
        var currentDayName= days[currentDay];
       document.write("You were born on "+currentDayName);
    }
}
```

You could also use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) to make date operations more easy.

Comment: thanks for this, I wouldn't have been able to figure this out at all. This is something we haven't gone over yet. Kinda just grazed the top of this in class.. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I won't write your homework for you, but this is generally what you want to do:

1. Get user's birthday
2. Create a `new Date` object with the date set to that birthday
3. Use the [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) method of the date object
4. Convert the number representing the day of the week to the actual string for that day.

Comment: Kinda just grazed the top of this in class.. thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function to get user input and convert it to a Date object. You can make it manually, but you'll know that this function is already implemented in web browsers if you search more.

Take a look at [this MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to see how you can make a Date object from a string. A document about [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) may also help you.